# ui-grid cellTypeCondition possible?

Tags: angularjs, types, conditional-statements, ui-grid

Does anyone know if it is possible in ui-grid to set type of cell using condition like cellEditableCondition ?

I need to set some editable rows type to text instead of number.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u should define algoritm to specify columns in columnDef

here is part from my working solution:

```
var type = '';
var cellFilter = '';
var widthLength = 100;
switch (value.Type) {
    case "int":
    case "bigint":
    case "numeric":
        type = 'number';
        widthLength = 120;
        break;
    case "date":
        type = 'dateStr';
        cellFilter = "date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'";
        widthLength = 90;
        break;
    case "datetime":
        type = 'dateStr';
        cellFilter = "date: 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm' : 'UTC'";
        widthLength = 120;
        break;
    case "bit":
        type = 'boolean';
        break;
    default:
        type = 'string';
        widthLength = 150;
        break;
}

var item = {
    name: value.Name,
    displayName: value.Name,
    minWidth: widthLength,
    width: '*',
    type: type
};
```

and when u fully define needed column just push it to `columnDefs` array.

```
$scope.yourGridName.columnDefs.push(item);
```

or

```
vm.yourGridName.columnDefs.push(item);
```

if u r using view model instead of `$scope`.